# Edit a vuetify modal form

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to edit a form created Vuetify, so I need to fill the fields with existing data who depends of card I click.
I use a dialog box modal to display it.

How can I did it ?

a example of my code, if you need more , let me know.

```
<template>
    <div class="editGroup">
        <v-dialog
                v-model="dialog"
                max-width="50%">

            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-icon class="penIcon" v-on="on">mdi-pencil-outline</v-icon>
            </template>

     <v-card>
       <p class="mt-12">Choose a name for your group</p>
       <v-text-field
       v-model="groupName"
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-card>
</template>


<script>
data() {
     return {
        groupName: ''
}
}

</script>
```

Edit: I'm passing the props of my groups object from parent to child(this component ).
How can I do to display the right data for the right card clicking ?

Comment: can you please update with complete code of your component, Im not seeing any v-card or v-modal..

Comment: edited on post.

Comment: Its not giving a clarity please try to create a code pen https://codepen.io/ so we can make code changes there